# Obfuscate filenames in XNA Content folder

Tags: file, xna, obfuscation, xna-4.0

I am using XNA 4 and Monogame to develop an application. Furthermore, I use EasFuscator to obfuscate the C# source code. Is it possible and what would be the best way to make the filenames in the content folder non-human readable?

Basically, a filename like "title_image.xnb" should automatically be renamed to something like "hdRv4EEdx.xnb" (just as an example). Encryption of the content is not necessarily needed.

Comment: The application is a game and I have a lot of revealing filenames like "secret winterworld.png" or "secret weapon 5 fire sound.wav". Those names are really convenient during delvelopment but should not be readable by players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this that I am aware of.

You can create a powershell script that will recursively go through all of your content files, then use regular expressions to find the appropriate Content.Load functions in your code and replace those with randomly generated hashes. You would then run this script as part of obfuscation.

It would probably even be simple to write if you have all of your Content.Load<> calls in a single file. Then the pseudocode would be something like:

```
For All Files in Content directory (and subdirectories, recursively):
  String hash = CreateRandomHash()
  File.renameTo(hash)
  "LoadContent.cs" = "LoadContent.cs".replace("Content.Load<Texture2D>(" + File.original.Name + ")", "Content.Load<Texture2D>(" + hash + ")");
```

But, you know, "pseudocode." :). It would take some work.

Comment: The problem with this aproach is that during development I want to keep the human-readable filenames. So the obfuscated filenames should only be used in the compiled Release version.

Comment: The script would be part of your obfuscation routine. Immediately prior to obfuscation, you would copy all of your source files and content files to a new directory, then run this script to replace the file names, then obfuscate the code. I mean, obfuscation also destroys readable code so it already does something like that.

Comment: Yes, this could work. As I have not much experience with scripting, could you maybe point me to a scripting language wherein such "copy/rename/replace text" can be done in a straightforward manner?

Comment: You can probably make a C# application for that. Use the System.IO namespace to go through the directory tree, use System.Random to generate hashes, use System.IO.File.ReadAllText() to read source files, System.IO.File.Rename/Move (something like that) to rename assets, System.Text.Regex to replace Content.Load calls. You could do this in Powershell, but if you're not experienced with it, writing C# code will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Why not adding all resources with those names into content manager, from code you will know that this is `title_image` and will not be readable from end users if they open folder.

```cs
title_image = Content.Load<Texture2D>("hdRv4EEdx");
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that but unfortunately I have more hundreds of graphical assets and hundreds of sound effects and I really would like to avoid doing this manually ;-)